# Find if a string has all unique chars using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Just brushing up on some simple java stuff. I am trying to check if a string is unique, and I figured the best way would be to do so through recursion. Here is what I have so far, but am getting an out of bounds error, obviously i'm overlooking something pretty simple:

```
public class uniqueCharString {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        String a = "abcdefghijk";
        System.out.println(unique(a));
    }

    public static boolean unique(String s){
        if(s.substring(1).contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)))){
            return false;
        }
        else return unique(s.substring(1));
    }

}
```

okay so I finished my way of thinking. I got some good advice from you guys, but I wanted to finish my thought process. How does this solution compare to some of the ones where you guys said use a set?

```
public static boolean unique(String s){
        for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++){
            if(s.substring(x+1).contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(x)))){
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `I figured the best way would be to do so through recursion` no no no

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'unique'? Is it that the same character should not appear twice? Also I agree with @Kon, recursion is rarely an efficient approach to String processing.

Comment: Yeah none of the same characters. Okay, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way to do this is with a Set. Iterate over each character and add them to a set. If the add operation returns false, then the character is already in your set and the String has not-all-unique chars, otherwise all are unique

```
String s = "some string blah blah blah";

Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
for (char c : s.toCharArray())
{
    boolean elementFirstAdded = set.add(c);
    if (!elementFirstAdded)
        //Duplicate
}
//Not duplicate
```

Comment: would this be most efficient tho? thanks for your response none the less

Comment: From a processing perspective, yes. Though this will use more space because it will double your String inside a Set

Comment: Set.add() returns "true if this set did **not** already contain the specified element", so I think you need `boolean duplicate = !set.add(c)`?

Comment: +1 That's pretty nice, I would have tried sorting them and then iterating over it and check if there are 2 consecutive characters that are the same, but this is better! :)

Comment: @Barney You are correct. Will make the edit, thanks for spotting it

Comment: @Pacane Your sorting solution will still be much better than recursion, but yes, it will still take O(n log n) time, while the approach above will take O(n) time only.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Kon said, a Set is (probably) more efficient.

However, to use recursion you need to add a termination condition: your function never returns true!

A zero or one length string must be unique (well, unique zero-length is a bit ambiguous...): add this at the top:

```
  if (s.length() <= 1) {
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, in case you're crazy about performance-tuning homework problems :)

```
public static boolean unique(String s) {
    BitSet chars = new BitSet(Character.SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (chars.get(c)) {
            return false;
        }
        chars.set(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The problem with performance tuning like this it that you don't really know if it is more performant unless you actually measure it. Compilers these days are pretty clever, and can do a lot of optimisation for you. Also, you have to define "performance": "faster" and "less memory usage" are two common (and often competing) criteria. Not saying this is bad in any way, just making the point that optimisation needs both a clear definition of what you are trying to optimise, and a test suite to measure it.

Comment: @Barney, you are totally right. And actually the first solution looks to be faster for whatever crazy reason! A mystery I'll solve later.

Comment: Never mind, I made a stupid mistake before - final conclusion is that the BitSet implementation is about 4x faster.

Comment: Good effort in actually writing a test class to measure it!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know what was duplicated I would just throw everything into the Set(), because a Set() cannot contain duplicates. They will never be added to the Set(). And if you just want to know if you had duplicates you can check the length of the String before and then the size of the HashSet() after.
Like this:

```
String a = "abcdefghijk";
String[] ary = a.split("");
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(words))

if (mySet.size() != ary.length){
     //do something
}
```

Comment: Will work, but not as efficient as @Kon's answer: this requires putting the entire string into the set, whereas Kon's approach stops as soon as a duplicate is found.

Comment: For the purpose of determining if the there are dups in the string you are correct. However if your using a set or a hashset you would never need to make that check to begin with. And added bonus if you are working with large strings they would be a lot more efficient to search.